# align two buttons horizontal to each other

Tags: html, css

How can I align two buttons horizontal to each other.

```
<input type="submit" class="app-button" id="btnSearch" value="Aply Filters"><br>
<input type="submit" class="app-button" id="btnClearSearch" value="Clear Filters">
```

Below is the CSS I am using.

```
.app-button{
     list-style: none;
     text-align: center;
     background-color: #01AAAD;
     width: 150px;margin:0;
     line-height: 60px;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kvv39v6x/1/)

Comment: may be need to delete <br> ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need something like this

(I only remove `<br>`, and wrap it into .row).

```css
.app-button{
    background-color: #01AAAD;
    width: 150px;
    margin:0 20px;
    display:inline-block;
    line-height: 60px;
}
.row{
  text-align:center;
  /*the same margin which is every button have, it is for small screen, and if you have many buttons.*/
  margin-left:-20px;
  marin-right:-20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <input type="submit" class="app-button" id="btnSearch" value="Aply Filters">
   <input type="submit" class="app-button" id="btnClearSearch" value="Clear Filters">
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this;

```
 .app-button{
     list-style: none;
     text-align: center;
     background-color: #01AAAD;
     width: 150px;margin:0;
     line-height: 60px;
     float: left;
   }
```

or you can try, `overFlow:hidden;`

Answer (score 0):

list-style is not needed. That's something used for ul and ol elements. You have two inputs, so one way would be :

```
.app-button {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #01AAAD;
    width: 150px;margin:0;
    line-height: 60px;
}
```

And with some space between maybe?

```
 .app-button:first-of-type {
    margin-right:15px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple method: 
HTML:

```
<div>
<input type="button" value="button1" /><input type="button" value="button2" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div { padding: 10px; border: 1px solid black; }
input { margin: 0; }
```